# getting error while performing a swap using token swap program

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, serum

const Web3 = require('@solana/web3.js')
const { TokenSwap, TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID, TokenSwapLayout } = require("@solana/spl-token-swap")
const token = require('@solana/spl-token')

async function main(){

```
const connection = new Web3.Connection('https://api.devnet.solana.com','confirmed')
const transaction = new Web3.Transaction()
//const transaction1 = new Web3.Transaction()
const tokenSwapStateAccount = Web3.Keypair.generate();
const phrase = [78,180,36,209,60,139,224,163,142,208,46,64,236,53,204,211,221,223,237,197,73,156,157,175,231,249,89,40,8,56,198,133,11,15,39,162,203,86,159,30,17,204,225,232,98,206,56,119,181,71,36,211,218,115,215,202,31,92,83,61,215,54,152,208]
const secret =  Uint8Array.from(phrase);
const wallet = Web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(secret);
const rent   = TokenSwap.getMinBalanceRentForExemptTokenSwap(connection)
const tokenSwapStateAccountInstruction = await Web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
     newAccountPubkey: tokenSwapStateAccount.publicKey,
     fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
     lamports: rent,
     space: TokenSwapLayout.span,
     programId: TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID
})
transaction.add(tokenSwapStateAccountInstruction)
console.log(1);

const [swapAuthority, bump] = await Web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
     [tokenSwapStateAccount.publicKey.toBuffer()],
     TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
```

)
// console.log(swapAuthority)
const tokenAMint = new Web3.PublicKey('AoAH8NBws97Fn4QFt9wpThBPzaTZt6aYqFqepTji3yT6')
const tokenBMint = new Web3.PublicKey('Eh3S2GHYJWQuGMgaKKcAJbkUNsU8XrBeVK4GzsQCmSJ3')

```
let tokenAAccountAddress = await token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
   tokenAMint, // mint
   swapAuthority, // owner
   true // allow owner off curve
```

)
//console.log(tokenAAccountAddress);
const tokenAAccountInstruction = await token.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
wallet.publicKey, // payer
tokenAAccountAddress, // ata
swapAuthority, // owner
tokenAMint // mint
)

transaction.add(tokenAAccountInstruction)

let tokenBAccountAddress = await token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
tokenBMint, // mint
swapAuthority, // owner
true // allow owner off curve
)

const tokenBAccountInstruction = await token.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
wallet.publicKey, // payer
tokenBAccountAddress, // ata
swapAuthority, // owner
tokenBMint // mint
)

transaction.add(tokenBAccountInstruction)
console.log(2);

const poolTokenMint = await token.createMint(
connection,
wallet,
swapAuthority,
null,
2

)
// console.log(poolTokenMint)
const tokenAccountPool = Web3.Keypair.generate()
// console.log(tokenAccountPool.publicKey)
//await connection.requestAirdrop(tokenAccountPool.publicKey,1e9)
const createTokenAccountPoolInstruction = Web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
newAccountPubkey: tokenAccountPool.publicKey,
space: token.ACCOUNT_SIZE,
lamports: rent,
programId: token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
})
//  console.log(createTokenAccountPoolInstruction);
// await connection.requestAirdrop(tokenAccountPool.publicKey,1e9)
//  console.log(tokenAccountPool);
const initializeTokenAccountPoolInstruction = token.createInitializeAccountInstruction(
tokenAccountPool.publicKey,
poolTokenMint,
wallet.publicKey
)
// console.log(initializeTokenAccountPoolInstruction);

transaction.add(createTokenAccountPoolInstruction)
transaction.add(initializeTokenAccountPoolInstruction)
console.log(3)
//await connection.requestAirdrop(tokenAccountPool.publicKey,1e9)
const feeOwner = new Web3.PublicKey('HfoTxFR1Tm6kGmWgYWD6J7YHVy1UwqSULUGVLXkJqaKN')

let tokenFeeAccountAddress = await token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
poolTokenMint, // mint
feeOwner, // owner
true // allow owner off curve
)

const tokenFeeAccountInstruction = await token.createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
wallet.publicKey, // payer
tokenFeeAccountAddress, // ata
feeOwner, // owner
poolTokenMint,// mint

)

transaction.add(tokenFeeAccountInstruction)
console.log(4);
//const poolTokenA= await token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(tokenAAccountAddress.publicKey, wallet.publicKey)
//const poolTokenB= await token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(tokenBAccountAddress.publicKey, wallet.publicKey)
//console.log(poolTokenA)

const createSwapInstruction = TokenSwap.createInitSwapInstruction(
tokenSwapStateAccount,      // Token swap state account
swapAuthority,              // Swap pool authority
tokenAAccountAddress,                 // Token A token account
tokenBAccountAddress,                 // Token B token account
poolTokenMint,              // Swap pool token mint
tokenFeeAccountAddress,     // Token fee account
tokenAccountPool.publicKey, // Swap pool token account
token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,     // Token Program ID
TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,      // Token Swap Program ID
0,                          // Trade fee numerator
10000,                      // Trade fee denominator
5,                          // Owner trade fee numerator
10000,                      // Owner trade fee denominator
0,                          // Owner withdraw fee numerator
0,                          // Owner withdraw fee denominator
20,                         // Host fee numerator
100,                        // Host fee denominator
//CurveType.ConstantProduct   // Curve type
)

transaction.add(createSwapInstruction)

console.log(5)
let userTokenA = await token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
tokenAMint, // mint
wallet.publicKey, // owner
true // allow owner off curve
)
let userTokenB = await token.getAssociatedTokenAddress(
tokenBMint, // mint
wallet.publicKey, // owner
true // allow owner off curve
)
const instruction = TokenSwap.depositAllTokenTypesInstruction(
tokenSwapStateAccount,
swapAuthority,
wallet.publickey,
userTokenA,
userTokenB,
tokenAAccountAddress,
tokenBAccountAddress,
poolTokenMint,
userTokenA,
TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
10 * 10 ** 2,
100e9,
100e9
)

transaction.add(instruction)

const swapInstruction = TokenSwap.swapInstruction(
tokenSwapStateAccount,
swapAuthority,
wallet.publicKey,
userTokenA,
tokenAMint,
tokenBMint,
userTokenB,
poolTokenMint,
tokenFeeAccountAddress,
null,
TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID,
token.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
10 * 10 **2,
0
)
console.log(swapInstruction)
transaction.add(swapInstruction)

const rec = await Web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection,transaction,[wallet,tokenSwapStateAccount,tokenAccountPool]);
console.log(rec);
}
main();

Comment: I've voted to close this question, unless you can add details, remove unnecessary details, and clarify which part of this code the error originates from. The text of the error message would be helpful, as well as the stack trace that points to the line of code that emits the error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are following this https://soldev.app/course/token-swap. the code here has a bug in this line

```
const rent = TokenSwap.getMinBalanceRentForExemptTokenSwap(connection)
```

it should be `await` ed. then you are using this promise in next function:

```
const tokenSwapStateAccountInstruction = await Web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
  newAccountPubkey: tokenSwapStateAccount.publicKey,
  fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
  // you are passing promise here, should be number
  lamports: rent,
  space: TokenSwapLayout.span,
  programId: TOKEN_SWAP_PROGRAM_ID
})
```

To solve this just `await`

```
const rent = await TokenSwap.getMinBalanceRentForExemptTokenSwap(connection);
```